# Test container error when starting docker from macbook m1

Tags: docker, docker-machine, apple-m1, testcontainers

I using macbook m1 and i have error when using test container from docker. When i start project using docker it throw me error

```
Docker machine "" does not exist
```

I install virtualbox using command :`brew install virtualbox --cask`

When i install success and start it throw me exception :

```
(default) Check network to re-create if needed...
(default) Creating a new host-only adapter produced an error: /usr/local/bin/VBoxManage hostonlyif create failed:
(default) 0%...
(default) Progress state: NS_ERROR_FAILURE
(default) VBoxManage: error: Failed to create the host-only adapter
(default) VBoxManage: error: VBoxNetAdpCtl: Error while adding new interface: failed to open /dev/vboxnetctl: No such file or directory
(default) VBoxManage: error: Details: code NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0x80004005), component HostNetworkInterfaceWrap, interface IHostNetworkInterface
(default) VBoxManage: error: Context: "RTEXITCODE handleCreate(HandlerArg *)" at line 95 of file VBoxManageHostonly.cpp
(default) 
(default) This is a known VirtualBox bug. Let's try to recover anyway...
Error setting up host only network on machine start: The host-only adapter we just created is not visible. This is a well known VirtualBox bug.
```

Now i cannot running testContainer because it required Docker machine. I cannot start because VirtualBox cannot running ? How to run it

Answer (score 4):

Try [Docker for Mac](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/install/).

Also, make sure that you're using the latest version of Testcontainers and that your JNA dependency is 5.7.0 or newer.

Comment: i using docker for mac but when i start project i required Docker machine "" .

Comment: @BaoTrungTran There is a hidden file .testcontainers.properties in your home directory. Can you post it's content?

Comment: Thanks you it now work but when i start it by testContainer it throw me exception :
Caused by: com.github.dockerjava.api.exception.DockerClientException: Could not pull image: no matching manifest for linux/arm64/v8 in the manifest list entries